# Constraining random number generation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to create a loop in Python with numpy that will give me a variable "times" with 5 numbers generated randomly between 0 and 20. However, I want there to be one condition: that none of the differences between two adjacent elements in that list are less than 1. What is the best way to achieve this? I tried with the last two lines of code, but this is most likely wrong.

```
for j in range(1,6):

    times = np.random.rand(1, 5) * 20
    times.sort()
    print times

    da = np.diff(times) 

    if da.sum < 1: break
```

For instance, for one iteration, this would not be good:

4.25230915 4.36463992 10.35915732 12.39446368 18.46893283

But something like this would be perfect:

1.47166904   6.85610453 10.81431629  12.10176092 15.53569052

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using numpy, you might as well use the built-in functions for uniform random numbers.

```
def uniform_min_range(a, b, n, min_dist):
    while True:
        x = np.random.uniform(a, b, size=n)
        np.sort(x)
        if np.all(np.diff(x) >= min_dist):
            return x
```

It uses the same trial-and-error approach as the previous answer, so depending on the parameters the time to find a solution can be large.

Comment: A numpy translation of the other answer is a definite plus

Comment: Thank you Hannes, it works perfectly and the numbers look great! I made x a global inside the function and the printed x outside, after passing the arguments.

Comment: No, please don't do that unless you really need to. Which you most likely don't :)  Instead call it as `times = uniform_min_range(0, 20, 5, 1.0)` and then `print times`.

Comment: Done! Thanks so much Hannes!

Answer (score 1):

Use a hit and miss approach to guarantee uniform distribution. Here is a straight-Python implementation which should be tweakable for numpy:

```
import random

def randSpacedPoints(n,a,b,minDist):
    #draws n random numbers in [a,b]
    # with property that their distance apart is >= minDist
    #uses a hit-miss approach

    while True:
        nums = [a + (b-a)*random.random() for i in range(n)]
        nums.sort()
        if all(nums[i] + minDist < nums[i+1] for i in range(n-1)):
            return nums
```

For example,

```
>>> randSpacedPoints(5,0,20,1)
[0.6681336968970486, 6.882374558960349, 9.73325447748434, 11.774594560239493, 16.009157676493903]
```

If there is no feasible solution this will hang in an infinite loop (so you might want to add a safety parameter which controls the number of trials).

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the limits http://imgur.com/j4iPNph It's probably because no misses can occur for (-1, 0) and (20, 21). Practically may not be important but I wanted to add as a note.

Comment: Thank you John! Unfortunately, since I am new to Python, I am still trying to wrap my head around your solution. I am copy pasting your code into my editor. I figured I should define the variables n, a, b, minDist in between the import and the def. But I don't the numbers. I get just a "** Load Time: 0.00 seconds"

Comment: @ayhan The numbers themselves are not uniform. The constraints force the numbers to be biased towards the end points. The uniformity I referred to is that the vector is chosen uniformly from among all such vectors.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are correct, I mixed up two different concepts.

Comment: @Spica The code was just a function definition. You have to pass the parameters to the function in order to get the function to return the list. Defining global variables with the same name as the function parameters doesn't pass those values to the function. Look at the bottom of my answer to see how to invoke the function.

Comment: Got it, John! I also added a print nums inside the def before calling it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Spica. Glad you got it to work, though from a programming point of view, adding a print statement *inside* a function like that makes it less usable as a function. It is better design to have the calling code print the result.

Comment: @John, indeed, I found that out when I tried Hannes function. For some reason printing inside the def was giving really weird results. Outside, alfter calling the function, it worked well.